# Can I talk to a deceased person in my mind?

Tags: halal-haram, death

My mum returned to Allah a year ago and I'm finding it very hard to cope. I often find myself "talking" to her in my mind.

Is this allowed in Islam?

I pray for her all the time, but I still talk to her in my mind.

Comment: I am so sorry for your loss. I hope you find the strength. I would like to say that maybe it would be wise to tell a doctor this. The loss of your mum may have put you in depression and should get checked out.

Comment: it is better to avoid talking to her like this, as this is not a normal practise. , though islam does not say anything clearly on it,but it is better to avoid it .

Comment: Jazak Allah khair.... I try my best to avoid it but sometimes it's difficult... I worry it may be shirak... So now I try an talk to Allah and just tell them that I miss my mum rather than saying in my mind " mum I miss you"... Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Indeed, **you will not make the dead hear**, nor will you make the deaf hear the call when they have turned their backs retreating. (Qur'an [27:80](http://quran.com/27/80))
>
> And not equal are the living and the dead. Indeed, Allah causes to hear whom He wills, but **you cannot make hear those in the graves.** (Qur'an [35:22](http://quran.com/35/22))

So, no matter how hard you try to communicate with your mum, (unless if she'z a [martyr](http://quran.com/2/154)), she's not gonna listen to you and remember when Allah says it in the Qur'an, that means he is being literal and he means it.

### Am 'I' safe?

Before talking if it's allowed or not, let me just recommend you to go through this guide - '[Getting started with Jinn](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0usGDDlyK7A)'.

Well, there are no implicit verses which say that simply talking to dead people is Haram or Shirk, but people fear this could very soon lead to that stage. After all, all a shaitan wants is that. Hence it is highly recommended to avoid it.

Here is a '[read more...](http://islamawareness.net/BlackMagic/fatwa_spirits.html)' explanation of how it could be considered shirk.

Anyways, as others have suggested, plz try to avoid it before it gets too worse and when a time comes when you really have to meet a psychologist.

May Allah forgive you're mum's sins and have mercy on her and [to him we belong](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/24122/11938) and ...

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Jazak ALLAH to all of you for clarifying my confusion... It's hard, but that's life, we all have to return back to ALLAH this is just a short journey May Allah reward my beautiful mum the highest rank in jannah, and may on the day of judgement I see my mum. Jazak Allah to all brothers and sisters who have guided me

Answer (score 2):

brother, you have to know that everything is allowed in islam, which is explicitly not forbidden.

As you are talking to her in your brain, in my own opinion (i am not a scholar) it should b avoided. as this type of interaction is not normal and is not beneficial for you. It may weaken your iman more than your sub-conscious does not want to let go of something, which Allah has taken. So i would suggest that you avoid it.

To cop with it, you should try to recite the supplications of morning and evening. (with loud voice) also, recite Surah baqara more and more all day (as much as you can).

I would also suggest you to contact an expert psychologist as well, as it is allowed in islam to be treated for such issues.

Comment: This disease needs no psychologist but a good iman doze. Also, plz try to support your stances from Qur'an and Hadith to give it more weight

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser: i agree brother. but in some patients, they do need medical care as well. So just gave him advice in case islamic cure does not have that much effect . but it rarely happens.