# What are the rulings of visitng graves and graves of pious people?

Tags: grave, tawassul

I am looking into the rulings established of what is permissible to do and not to do when visiting a grave in general, and visiting graves of prophets and pious people.

This question was spurred from discussions in [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37858/can-a-muslim-woman-go-on-arbaeen-pilgrimage-without-a-mahram/). I tried to search my best, but I really found it rather difficult. Many sources I found of different schools of Fiqh tells that it is okay to visit a grave, but there are certain innovations that should not be done, but they don't go on telling what are they. I am looking for the views of four schools of Fiqh, as to draw a general guideline.

Comment: I think this answers your question http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/7312/13438

Answer (score 1):

Permission to visit the Graves:

The Four main sects, shia's, deobandi's, brailvi's, and Whabbis have different point of views for visiting graves.

[Shia's](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/topic/234934639-visiting-graves-shia-sunni-perspectives/) and [Bralevi's](http://www.ahlus-sunna.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=61&Itemid=163) encourage visiting graves. A good example would be Arbaeen, as mentioned in the question's link, where Million marches towards the Grave of Imam Hussain. They encourage this act through the following:

1. Voice against oppression (as Imam Hussain stood against tyranny)
2. Prayers alongside graves (as they ask for Allah's mercy for the sake of the person in the grave), also called In Reference to the person in the grave.
3. Strong relation to Allah (as when they visit the grave, they remember that, this life has to pass on, and everything will be left behind).

[Deobandi's](http://islamsalvationfromhell.blogspot.com/2015/09/deobandi-belief-punishment-of-grave.html) and [Wahabbi's](https://www.al-islam.org/wahhabism-ayatullah-jafar-subhani/wahhabis-and-renovation-graves-awliya-allah) discourage visiting graves. They support it by these points:

1. One who is dead, cannot be asked from directly as it is kufr, Even from Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) as Zakir Naik(Deobandi) said on his address on television show.
2. Some one cannot ask from anyone but Allah. As only Allah can help you.

The Main point of Argument Remain same always, Asking for Allah Mercy with-reference to the pious people who has passed away and Asking for Allah mercy without-reference?

With this Point in mind, do remember each sect follow its rules.

Comment: This answer looks like it would benefit from some reliable references.

Comment: Sure it will. Just have added some references. Hope it helps

Comment: @SyedMZulqarnain The groups you mentioned are sects but not schools of thought in fiqh.

Comment: OK, i update it now, thanks for showing it, although i thought they were same thing, but anyhow, it's better now.